# change scala version to 2.11 on intellij for spark application

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea

I am a beginner in scala and spark, i want to install spark for scala using intellij. to use spark 2.2.0 i need scala 2.11, when i creat the project, I have chosen the 2.11.0 version. on build.sbt file i can see

```
name := "untitled" version := "0.1" scalaVersion := "2.11.0"
```

[version selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3onmk.png)

when i run the code, i got this error

```
Error:scalac: No 'scala-library*.jar' in Scala compiler classpath in Scala SDK SBT: org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.11.0:jar
```

I tried to change the scala version, using Global Libraries + scala SDK and i try to download scala 2.11, but I have an error while downloading

like in this image
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bmhFt.png)

someone can help me please ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not your sbt file.

Close the project and try to open your build.sbt as a project. After that is supposed to work.

You are supposed to have already installed the scala plugin.

After install scala plugin just do the following steps:

- At main menu click at "Open"
- Select the file build.sbt you created
- Select the option "Open File as a project"

if you are already in a some project:

- Menu "File -> Open"
- Select the file build.sbt you created
- Select the option "Open File as a project"

It is a good idea take a look at this website to understand a little about build.sbt file: [Create a project directory with source code](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.12.4/docs/Getting-Started/Hello.html)

The video [stalling and Using IntelliJ IDEA IDE to Develop Scala program](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=epr9ZHUuqCw) contains valuable information for beginners.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Hello, thank you, but how can iopen sbt file as project ?